# Does PHP Email script leave a record anywhere (like in cPanel?)

Tags: php, email, cpanel

The title basically says it all.

We've got a subdomain setup where every single subdomain is the same exact site, but branded for different companies.

There's a PHP script that sends an email based on certain actions when a form is submitted. Is there anyway (possibly in cPanel) to see a record of those sent emails? Or will I have to code something in to that script?

Comment: Is the script something you can view/edit?  What is the code actually physically doing in the script?

Comment: your mail server can probably do this.

Comment: cpanel has some functionality to do it. unfortunately i cant give more info because i dont remember =/. search antispam tools or something like that

Comment: @David yes I can edit it, I wrote it. It's just a complex version of php's `mail()` function to grab variables based on input, and it sends an email to the current user (who sent the form) and the owner of the website. The code isn't necessary

Comment: @AlexDemchak: The question you're essentially asking is, "Does this script just send an email, or does it also record in a log somewhere that an email was sent?"  The code _is_ necessary to know this.  If you wrote the script, what did you _write_ it to do?  I assume it sends a message to an SMTP service, but does it log anything anywhere?  Conversely, if it's not logging anything in the code, do you also own the SMTP service and is _that_ logging anything?  It seems like you would have the answers you're looking for already.

Comment: I was wondering if the mail function itself created a record on the server. Not if there was a logging function in the code. I was looking forward to NOT having to write it, and that the server would take care of it on it's own on every successful `mail()` execution, however seemingly thats not the case, so I've accepted the answer below for giving me a solution to add to my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If mail() encounters an error, this usually logs the error in this location: /var/log/messages (unix path)

Otherwise, logging is as easy as adding few extra lines of code when you are calling the mail() function.

```
$file = "mail.log"; // log file name
$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file"); // create a handle
fwrite($fh, "to: ".$to.",subject: ".$subject.", body: ".$body."\n"); // log email sent
fclose($fh); // close file
```

Comment: Thanks for actually giving me a solution - with some modifications, it works great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to do this work in your application itself.  Then you have control over the format, and can use that data in your application at a later point, if necessary.

Comment: I am planning on building in a recording functionality at some point - but for now I was just wondering if there IS a record of those emails anywhere on the server, regardless of format or usability

Comment: @AlexDemchak, How should we know?  There are thousands of ways to configure your mail server, and thousands of ways your script could be already set up with this functionality.  Records like this are not typical, but it's possible they are there.

Comment: I wouldn't know if you would know. I just wanted to know that is using basic php `mail()` functionality left a record. I was hoping for a "Yes, it can be found *HERE* in cPanel". Guess I'll dig around some more

Comment: @AlexDemchak, No, the `mail()` function does nothing but pass off mail to sendmail (or SMTP in the case of Windows).  If you're on *nix, you can probably write a script that writes to a file, and configure that as your sendmail script.